# Using Observable.from and flatMap to perform operation on each item in an List and to set the result in each list element

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, flatmap

I get a List of searchItems. For each element in this list exists a Lat und Lng. For these coordinates I use a googleService that takes these two values and returns a JsonObject with the name (city name) for this location. This works fine! In my onNext I can see in my log output the city.

Now my problem: I want to store this name in the corresponding list element. like: item.setLocation(loc) -> but I can not set access to the item in onNext() ! how can I get access to item ??

```
 Observable.from(searchItems)
            .flatMap(item -> googleService.getCityNameFromLatLngObserable(item.getLat(), item.getLng(), null)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    view.updateSearches(searchItem);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(JsonObject response) {
                    if (response.get("results").getAsJsonArray().size() > 0) {
                        String loc = response.get("results").getAsJsonArray()
                                .get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("address_components").getAsJsonArray()
                                .get(2).getAsJsonObject().get("long_name").toString();
                        Log.d("CONAN", "City: "+loc);

                        item.setLocation(loc); //does not work
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you shouldn't really change your `searchItems` but rather create new ones with the new info. This is to enforce immutability, which is very dear to Rx.

There is more than one way to do this, but here's one possible way. You need the item to call your Google service so you cannot use `zip` or any of its friends. So let's keep the first bit like you have it and get an observable emitting each search item:

```
Observable.from(searchItems)
```

Now let's go on and create new search items with their location.

```
Observable.from(searchItems)
          .flatMap(item -> googleService
                              .getCityNameFromLatLngObserable(
                                    item.getLat(),
                                    item.getLng(), null)
                              .map(jsonObject -> /* create a 
                                                    new item with location */))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(new Subscriber<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                view.updateSearches(searchItem);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Item item) {
                   // Your items with location
            }
        });
```

What I did was map the results of the `googleService. getCityNameFromLatLngObserable` to an item that has the location from the result. Notice how here you have access to both the item and the json object return by google?

Now inside the map function you can either use a function such as `createWithLocation(item, getLocation(jsonObject))` or use something like the builder pattern:

```
item.toBuilder()
    .location(getLocation(jsonObject))
    .build();
```

Notice also that on the subscriber `onNext` you have now an `Item` instead of a `JsonObject` and with the location filled. I assume you can code `getLocation` since your example already has this.

One last thing, you can also call the setter in the item instance and not create a new one. I would advise against this because you'll be adding a side effect to a call that others might not expect. It's usually a source for bugs. However, you can still do it :)

Hope it helps